# how to disable datepicker depending on value in select tag in ANTD table

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx, antd

I have a ANT table inside one of the forms I'm developing. there is one select and 2 date pickers in this table. the date pickers need to be disabled when a particular value is selected in the select operator. how can i do this. please help.

```
    const EditableContext = React.createContext();
    const EditableRow = ({ form, index, ...props }) => (
      <EditableContext.Provider value={form}>
        <tr {...props} />
      </EditableContext.Provider>
    );
    const EditableFormRow = Form.create()(EditableRow);
    class EditableCell extends React.Component {
      state = {
        editing: false,
        apiManager:[]
      };

     getInput = dataIndex => {
        switch (dataIndex) {
          case "type":
            return (
           case "req_type":
            return (
              <Select
                ref={node => (this.input = node)}
                onPressEnter={this.save}
                onBlur={this.save}
                placeholder="Select"
                name="ftpidselect"
              >
                {req_type_dropdown.map(person => (
                  <Option value={person.name} label={person.name} key={person.name}>
                    {person.name}
                  </Option>
                ))}
              </Select>
            );
            break;
          case "validity_from":
            return (
              <input
                type="date"
                format="DD-MM-YYYY"
                ref={node => (this.input = node)}
                onPressEnter={this.save}
                onBlur={this.save}
                placeholder="Select"
                style={{ height: 40, width: 120 }}
                name="ftpidselect"
              />
            );
            break;
          case "validity_to":
            return (
              <input
                type="date"
                format="DD-MM-YYYY"
                ref={node => (this.input = node)}
                onPressEnter={this.save}
                onBlur={this.save}
                placeholder="Select"
                style={{ height: 40, width: 120 }}
                name="ftpidselect"
              />
            );
            break;
          default:
            return (
              <Input
                ref={node => (this.input = node)}
                onPressEnter={this.save}
                onBlur={this.save}
                placeholder="add data"
              />
            );
            break;
        }
      };
     toggleEdit = () => {
        const editing = !this.state.editing;
        this.setState({ editing }, () => {
          if (editing) {
            this.input.focus();
          }
        });
      };

      save = e => {
        const { record, handleSave } = this.props;
        this.form.validateFields((error, values) => {
          if (error && error[e.currentTarget.id]) {
            return;
          }
          this.toggleEdit();
          handleSave({ ...record, ...values });
        });
      };

      renderCell = form => {
        this.form = form;
        const { children, dataIndex, record, title } = this.props;
        const { editing } = this.state;
        return editing ? (
          <Form.Item style={{ margin: 0 }}>
            {form.getFieldDecorator(dataIndex, {
              rules: [
                {
                  required: true,
                  message: `${title} is required`
                }
              ],
              initialValue: record[dataIndex]
            })(this.getInput(dataIndex))}
          </Form.Item>
        ) : (
          <div
            className="editable-cell-value-wrap"
            style={{ paddingRight: 24 }}
            onClick={this.toggleEdit}
          >
            {children}
          </div>
        );
      };
     render() {
        const {
          editable,
          dataIndex,
          title,
          record,
          inputType,
          index,
          handleSave,
          children,
          ...restProps
        } = this.props;
        return (
          <td {...restProps}>
            {editable ? (
              <EditableContext.Consumer>{this.renderCell}</EditableContext.Consumer>
            ) : (
              children
            )}
          </td>
        );
      }
    }
    export class IDrequesttable extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          backupof: [],
          data: []
        };
        this.columns = [
          {
            title: "Requirement Type",
            dataIndex: "req_type",
            align: "center",
            width: 180,
            editable: true
          },
          {
            title: "Validity From",
            dataIndex: "validity_from",
            align: "center",
            width: 130,
            editable: true
          },
          {
            title: "Validity To",
            dataIndex: "validity_to",
            align: "center",
            width: 130,
            editable: true
          },
        ];
     this.state = {
          dataSource: [
            {
              key: "0"
            }
          ],
          count: 1
        };
      }
    handleAdd = () => {
        const { count, dataSource } = this.state;
        console.log("datasource.....", this.state);
        const newData = {
          key: count
        };
        this.setState({
          dataSource: [...dataSource, newData],
          count: count + 1
        });
      };

      handleSave = row => {
        const newData = [...this.state.dataSource];
        const index = newData.findIndex(item => row.key === item.key);
        const item = newData[index];
        newData.splice(index, 1, {
          ...item,
          ...row
        });
        this.setState({ dataSource: newData });
        ftpid = Array.from(newData);
      };

      render() {
        const { dataSource } = this.state;
        const components = {
          body: {
            row: EditableFormRow,
            cell: EditableCell
          }
        };
        const columns = this.columns.map(col => {
          if (!col.editable) {
            return col;
          }
          return {
        ...col,
        onCell: record => ({
          record,
          editable: col.editable,
          dataIndex: col.dataIndex,
          inputType: col.dataIndex === "folder_owner" ? "email" : "text",
          title: col.title,
          handleSave: this.handleSave
        })
      };
    });
    return (
      <div>
        <Table
          components={components}
          rowClassName={() => "editable-row"}
          bordered
          dataSource={dataSource}
          columns={columns}
          size='small'
          // scroll={{x:1500}}
          style={{ overflowX: "scroll" }}
        />
        <Button
          onClick={this.handleAdd}
          style={{ marginTop: 16, float: "right" }}
        >
          Add a row
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I tried using a global variable to toggle the disabled in the datepickers but that didn't work.

Comment: Try adding a minimal reproducible example, [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Its hard to follow all this code, also in your case, it seems you need a "disabled" state and a callback on clicking the specific select

Comment: thanks for replying. I'll try to come up with a minimal example.

Answer (score 1):

I found a fix. I don't know if it will be a permanent fix or not. I edited the `renderCell` to pass `record` with `dataIndex` to the `this.getInput`.

```
renderCell = form => {
    this.form = form;
    const { children, dataIndex, record, title } = this.props;
    const { editing } = this.state;
    return editing ? (
      <Form.Item style={{ margin: 0 }}>
        {form.getFieldDecorator(dataIndex, {
          rules: [
            {
              required: dataIndex=="remark"?false:true,
              message: `required`
            }
          ],
          initialValue: record[dataIndex]
        })(
          (this.getInput(dataIndex,record)))}
      </Form.Item>
    ) : (
      <div
        className="editable-cell-value-wrap"
        style={{ paddingRight: 24 }}
        onClick={this.toggleEdit}
      >
        {children}
      </div>
    );
  };
```

Then in `getInput` I added `disabled`

```
case "validity_from":
        return (
          <input
            type="date"
            format="DD-MM-YYYY"
            ref={node => (this.input = node)}
            onPressEnter={this.save}
            onBlur={this.save}
            placeholder="Select"
            disabled={record.req_type=="Permanant"?true:false}
            style={{ height: 40, width: 120 }}
            name="ftpidselect"
          />
        );
        break;
      case "validity_to":
        return (
          <input
            type="date"
            format="DD-MM-YYYY"
            ref={node => (this.input = node)}
            onPressEnter={this.save}
            onBlur={this.save}
            placeholder="Select"
            disabled={record.req_type=="Permanant"?true:false}
            style={{ height: 40, width: 120 }}
            name="ftpidselect"
          />
        );
```

I still don't know if this will be a viable solution.